# Excel: Calculation of sum of increases (decreases) in range, just in one formula

Tags: excel, range, formula

I want to calculate sum of increases (decreases) in range. I cannot figure out it with SUMIF function. Values in cells A2:A8 are as below (also in pic). I want to write formula in C2 (increases) and in D2 (decreases). After writing formula C2 should be 30, and D2 should be 17.

A2: 1
A3: 12
A4: 4
A5: 8
A6: 15
A7: 23
A8: 14

[Picture of screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3deGx.jpg)

Comment: Try =SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A7<A3:A8),--(A3:A8-A2:A7))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT for this:
Check for each cell if it is bigger / smaller than the one above: --(A2:A7

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A7<A3:A8),--(A3:A8-A2:A7))
```

For decreasees:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A8<A2:A7),--(A3:A8-A2:A7))
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. 
And is it possible to calculate with formula if cell "A5" is "13/8"? 13/8 means that from "A4", "4" increased to "13" and in the current cell "13" decreased to "8". Formula should consider this. Then C2 and D2 should be 35 and 22.

A2: 1 A3: 12 A4: 4 A5: 13/8 A6: 15 A7: 23 A8: 14

Comment: And why don't you insert a cell between A4 and A5 with a Value of 13?